# Maximum sum of two elements in an array minus the distance between them

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sum, max, distance

I am trying to find the maximum sum of two elements in an array minus the distance between them.
Specifically I am trying to calculate max{ a[i]+a[j]-|i-j| }
I am currently stuck. I have obviously considered the naive approach (O(n^2)). However ,I am pretty sure there is a better ,more efficient approach (O(nlogn)) or even O(n). 
Can someone please help me on how to approach the problem. I would be grateful if anyone threw some hints or a simple idea to have something to start from. Sorting the array first? Maybe using a dynamic programming approach?

Edit:
I think I have found an O(n) solution
Let's assume that our max sum comes from a[i] and a[j] , a[i] contributes to that sum with : a[i]+i . a[j] contributes to that sum with a[j]-j. (Because our sum is a[i]+a[j]-|j-i|= a[i]+a[j]+i-j. )
Approach: for convenience we compute the matrices A_plus_index=a[i]+i and A_minus_index=a[i]-i.
Then we use two helping arrays: 
 i) The first one has for every i ,the max value of A_plus_index array considering only the elements from 0 to i. 
ii) The second has for every i, the max value of A_minus_index array considering only the elements from N to i ,where N is the length of array a.
Now we traverse the arrays once and find the max: A_plus_index[i]+ A_minus_index[i+1].
Total complexity O(n).

Comment: Consider a[i]. What would it contribute to a combination with a[j], j>i? Now consider all a[j], j>i. Which one would contribute the most to a combination with a[i]?

Comment: If I understand what you are saying,your approach is to consider all a[j] (j>i) for every a[i] in order to find the one a[j] which maximizes  the sum a[i]+a[j]-|i-j| for every a[i].That's O(n^2). Excuse me if I didn't get what you are saying right.

Comment: you could probably create a data structure that is faster to search, but creating the data structure would be at least n^2 so won't really help you. You can short circuit your search by finding the distance between the two biggest elements and only searching that distance. But worst case is the same

Comment: **No.** If you think about the question for *one* a[i], you may be able to see how to decouple a[i] from a[j], and then perhaps you can see how to do the whole search in one pass, O(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JeffersonWhite your idea works and you could post it as an answer and accept it.

But I am going to improve upon your idea a little bit:

You could build only one array instead of 2, which contains the maximum of `A[j] - j` so far for each `j` from `N-1` to `1`.

And then traverse the array forward each time computing the `max( A[i] + i + max_so_far-_reverse[i+1])`

```
//Building the reverse array
max_so_far_reverse = array of length N
max_reverse = A[N-1]-(N-1)
max_so_far_reverse[N-1] = max_reverse
for j = N-2 to 1:
   max_reverse = max(max_reverse, A[j]-j)
   max_so_far_reverse[j] = max_reverse

//Computing maximum value by traversing forward
max = 0
for i = 0 to N-2:
    max = max(max, A[i] + i + max_so_far_reverse[i+1])

return max
```