# print the maximum value of x where x = |(A[i] – A[j]) + (i – j)|

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

*️Problem asked in Directi Interview*

Take an input array, say A and print the maximum value of x
where `x = |(A[i] – A[j]) + (i – j)|`

```
Constraints:
Max array size: 20000
Time limit: 0.1s
```

Time limit is a major factor in this question.

Here is the setter's solution for this question.

```
'''
THE BRUTE FORCE APPROACH
def maximum(arr):
    res=0            
    n=len(arr)
    for i in range (n):
        for j in range(n):
            res=max(res,abs(arr[i]-arr[j])+abs(i-j))
    return res 
'''
import sys


def maximum(arr):
    max1=max2=-sys.maxsize-1
    min1=min2=sys.maxsize
    ans=0
    n=len(arr)
    for i in range(n):   
        max1=max(max1,arr[i]+i)
        max2=max(max2,arr[i]-i)
        min1=min(min1,arr[i]+i)
        min2=min(min2,arr[i]-i)
    ans=max(ans,max2-min2)    
    ans=max(ans,max1-min1)
    return ans
```

But I tried solving the problem using `sort`

```
def maximum(array):
    n=len(array)
    array.sort()
    return (array[n-1]-array[0]) + (n-1)
    
    
if __name__=="__main__":
    n=int(input())
    array= list(map(int,input("\nEnter the numbers : ").strip().split()))[:n]
    print(maximum(array))
```

Is my approach correct ? Is it optimised?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The setter’s solution traverses the array just once. If n is the length of the array, that solution does some number of operations proportional to n. When you sort the array, that generally requires some number of operations proportional to n•log n. So that is not an optimized solution.

Comment: Well when you solve using sorting the numbers in the array change their indexes, so it will give you WA.(There exists an i such as A[i] != sorted_A[i] except if A is sorted)

Comment: The answer is incorrect, take the counter example of: [2,1,3]

The solution for this problem should yield 3: `(3-1) + (2-1)` or `(3-2) + (2-0)`
However, suggested solution will yield 4: `(3-1) + (2-0)`

Comment: Similar question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60591517/maximum-sum-of-two-elements-in-an-array-minus-the-distance-between-them/60600805#60600805

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer suggested, of first sorting and taking the elements, is incorrect. Take the counter example of: `[2,1,3]`

- The solution for this problem should yield 3: `(3-1) + (2-1)` or
  `(3-2) + (2-0)`
- However, suggested solution will yield 4: `(3-1) + (2-0)`

---

A possible (linear time) solution:

Let's start with some algebra, and drop the absolute value for a minute.

```
(A[i] – A[j]) + (i – j) = (A[i] + i) - (A[j] + j)
```

We are looking for maximal value, so

- We want to minimize the value of `(A[j] + j)`
- We want to maximize the value of `(A[i] + i)`.
- Note that they are completely independent of each other.

You can find two integers, one that maximizes `(A[i] + i)`, and the other that minimizes `(A[j] + j)`. Finding such 2 numbers can be done simply in linear pass.

Repeat for the other way around (when `(A[i] – A[j]) + (i – j)` is negative):

- Find i that minimizes `(A[i] + i)`
- Fine `j` that maximizes `(A[j] + j)`.

Both are done in linear time, yielding `O(n)` solution

Comment: Generally speaking, [edits are not for adding information](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), but as clarifications. The edit simply didn't "feel right" to me in the context of this answer, even though there was nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting disturbs the original array and the mapping of elements at their respective indices gets lost. So logically, sorting will lead to wrong answer.

For example, as correctly described by @amit in his comments:

A = [2, 1, 3]

Correct answer = 3

Suggested solution's answer = 4